# Parallel Deployment on Tomcat with open sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat with parallel deployment for updating my application.

Problem: my app opens a socket on a fixed port. So when I deploy an addition application like `myapp##2.war`, this would try to open the same socket as `myapp##1.war`.

Question: is it possible that Tomcat itself opens a socket, and then delegates any incoming requests to the specific port the application opened? So that from the outside always the same port is accessibly, even though internally this is routed to different ports?

Comment: I agree. The problem is that your application opens a socket. Why does it do that? You could use a Websocket, for example.

Comment: The application is used for communcation with a legacy system. This system can only connect to an open traditional socket.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite certain on the topology, communication flow and actual use case but I would suggest you deploy something between your web app(s) and the actual remote socket. have a loop at Apache Camel (which can be deployed via tomcat if I am not mistaken) and can deal with the socket connection, giving you higher level endpoints for your WARs.
check the [netty socket](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html) connector.

Answer (score -1):

1. Resources can be shared between web applications if you

   1. Add the resource to `GlobalNamingResources` element in file `server.xml` ([reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/globalresources.html), [howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html))
   2. Add a `ResourceLink` element for it in the context file of your web application, `META-INF/context.xml` ([reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Links)).

   A resource can be anything. E.g. a global AtomicReference that can hold a shared object can be created like this:

   ```
   <Resource
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
    name="foo/bar"
    singleton="true"
    type="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference"/>
   ```

   If you put anything into such AtomicReference, beware of [classloader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) lifecycle issues for those objects. If the shared object was created by a web application, it must be cleared before the web application stops, as its classloader will be inaccessible afterwards.

   If you have an open port, essentially it means that there is some component that listens for incoming connections on that port. It accepts a connection and forwards it for further processing elsewhere.
2. Re: *delegates any incoming requests to the specific port*.

   Port forwarding can be done by firewalls and by proxies. E.g. there is [well known recipe](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_to_run_Tomcat_without_root_privileges.3F) to configure iptables to forward 80 → 8080 or 443 → 8443).

Comment: This still doesn't answer how to deploy the same application twice then (because it would have the same port during parallel deployment)...

Answer (score -1):

You ***can do*** it by configuring the web server to listen on the specific/fixed port & let it do the port forwarding/route forwarding to the two web applications running on different ports internally.

Let's say `app1` & `app2` are running on `8001` & `8002` respectively.

Now you can configure the web server to do the route forwarding like below. Of course, some sort of distinction is required - For the below example the distinction is based on the URL resource:

```
ProxyPass        /app1/resource http://localhost:8001/app1/
ProxyPassReverse /app1/resource http://localhost:8001/app1/

ProxyPass        /app2/resource http://localhost:8002/app2/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/resource http://localhost:8002/app2/
```

Read more about [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

The route forwarding will work as follows:

- `www.example.com/app1/resource` will go to `http://localhost:8001/app1/`
- `www.example.com/app2/resource` will go to `http://localhost:8002/app2/`

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12872051/820410) also.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to run them asynchronously then pooling is a good idea, which I've done with just two threads.  What you can do is add a JDBCtemplate to the configuration that is really simple with Tomcat 7 or newer.  Some of the advantages:
 - Tomcat jdbc pool implements the ability retrieve a connection asynchronously, without adding additional threads to the library itself.
 - Tomcat jdbc pool is a Tomcat module, it depends on Tomcat JULI, a simplified logging framework used in Tomcat.
 - Retrieve the underlying connection using the javax.sql.PooledConnection interface.
Starvation proof. If a pool is empty, and threads are waiting for a connection, when a connection is returned, the pool will awake the correct thread waiting. Most pools will simply starve.

Add this resource to the server.xml [JDBCTemplate Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Asynchronous_Connection_Retrieval) https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Asynchronous_Connection_Retrieval

I'm assuming you have additional inputs the application has accessing the ports so extensiblity is what this gives you.  You can test the application if you use JDBCTemplate as you start building an application that could get larger.

Comment: This is not about db connections, but SOCKETS!